# Multiple Startup Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-live-player

I'am using VS 2017 with a webapi and xamarim forms project.

I configured the xamarin live player and managed to use it successfully, but when I put it to run along with the webapi project, only the android project starts (On Live Player).

Startup options:

[image]

I've already tried

- Reinstall visual studio.
- Restart machine
- Run visual studio as administrator
- Clear caches

Nothing worked.

Is this a known problem?

Answer (score 0):

For a similar use case, my approach is always to keep separated projects and to run them in two different instances of Visual Studio (or Rider, or whatever else). Also because usually if you need to change the api you can test with something different to your mobile app (with Postman for example, or with ARC), and once that api are working I usually develop only the mobile app.

About multiple startup projects I've never had problems with more "server projects", I tried to add a simple Android app to the solution and even if it correctly works when launched alone, doesn't work when I try to run it with other projects.

[image].